# What is GIT Staging and Difference between Add To Index and Add To GIT Index?

Tags: egit, git-index, git-stage

I am using GibHub private repository. I don't have enough knowledge about it.
What is Git Staging ? what is the purpose of Git Staging ?
When to use Git Staging ?
I found two different options to add file in Git Staging.

1. Project Explorer --> Team --> Add to index
2. Team Synchronize --> Add to Git Index

Both of them send files to Git Staging. Then What is the difference between these two ?
Which is better to user ? Both of them send files to Git Staging.

Thanks.

Comment: What tool are you using? Eclipse? GitHub for Windows? Visual Studio?

Comment: @VonC Those commands belongs to Eclipse/EGit. I've updated the tags accordingly

Comment: @nulltoken I know and I am not convinced.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and Git plugin to access GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

They do the same thing. It's just an inconsistency in the labeling.

I [pushed a change for EGit](https://git.eclipse.org/r/29854) to make this consistent, it will be in the next release (3.5).

Answer (score 1):

**"Staging"** is the process that one performs when selecting which modified files (or portion of files) will be part of the next commit.

The **"Index"** is the file into which Git stores the files that have been staged. It's also called the **"Staging area"**.

Adding a file to the index is merely saying *"Git, this version of this file in my working directory should be part of the next commit I'm about to create"*.

References:

- **[Egit - User guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide)**
- **[ProGit - Recording changes to the repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository)**